# Configure Xtext generator at runtime

Tags: eclipse, generator, xtext, inject, preference

I have implemented with Xtext a DSL, and I'm trying to find a way to configure dynamically the generation of code in mydsl.ui Eclipse plugin.

I introduced a preference parameter in order to configure generator.

I injected a custom GeneratorConfiguration object with MyDslRuntimeModule

Then I set the preference parameter in this object in "build" method of a custom BuilderParticipant (configured in plugin.xml).

```java
// In mydsl plugin    
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    def Class<? extends IGeneratorConfiguration> bindIGeneratorConfiguration() {
        return GeneratorConfiguration;
   }

}

// In mydsl.ui plugin
package mydsl.ui;

public class MyBuildPartecipant extends BuilderParticipant {

@Inject IGeneratorConfiguration generatorConfiguration;

@Override
public void build(IBuildContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

    ScopedPreferenceStore scopedPreferenceStore = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "ID");

    generatorConfiguration.setGeneratorProperty(scopedPreferenceStore.getInt("myDslProperty"));

    super.build(context, monitor);
}

// In mydsl plugin
class MyDslGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

@Inject IGeneratorConfiguration generatorConfiguration;

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {

        println("Compiling with " + generatorConfiguration.generatorProperty)
```

The result is that the GeneratorConfiguration object obtained via @Inject decorator in class MyBuildPartecipant of mydsl.ui plugin (eclipse ui) is different from that obtained in class MyDslGenerator of mydsl plugin (Xtext generator plugin).

How can I pass a parameter from eclipse ui plugin to Xtext generator plugin (non ui plugin) in order to configure dynamically the code generation?

Thanks
Paolo

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```java
// In mydsl plugin    
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    def IGeneratorConfiguration bindIGeneratorConfiguration() {
        return new GeneratorConfiguration();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should mark the `GeneratorConfiguration` class with `@Singleton`.

or add a singleton binding using a configure method

```
def void configureIGeneratorConfiguration(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(IGeneratorConfiguration).to(GeneratorConfiguration).in(Scopes.SINGLETON)
}
```

or annotate the class binding with `@SingletonBinding`

```
@SingletonBinding
def Class<? extends IGeneratorConfiguration> bindIGeneratorConfiguration() {
    GeneratorConfiguration
}
```

the way you do it wont work if you inject stuff into the GeneratorConfiguration class

Comment: Thank you for support and for your contribution to Xtext. My mistake arose from the copy of AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule,  `public Class<? extends IGenerator2> bindIGenerator2() {
  return MyDslGenerator.class;
 } ` behaves like a singleton.

Comment: it actually does not. there is only once place the generator is created so it is "one instance only" but not a singleton